# Setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH on Mac OS X Sierra (CoolProp)

Tags: excel, macos, dyld

Disclaimer: This question started as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/issues/1430#issuecomment-290430248).

## Question

I'll put [the X question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right up front:
**Does anyone know a way to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a way that Excel 2016 will recognize on MacOS Sierra?**

The actual problem (Y): **How (else) can the developers of CoolProp allow their dynamic library to be used in Excel?**

## Background

I am trying to get Excel 2016 for Mac to recognize the CoolProp plugin using [these instructions](http://www.coolprop.org/dev/coolprop/wrappers/Excel/index.html#pre-compiled-binaries-for-osx), which basically boil down to using this `startup.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>my.startup</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>sh</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/Users/$USER/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office"</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a location where Excel can access the dynamic library and copying the `libCoolProp.dylib` file into that same directory. Unfortunately, it appears that due to SIP, one can no longer set any environment variable which starts with `DYLD_`.

To verify this, I have built a test spreadsheet which contains this VBA function and `=ENV("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")` in cell A1.

```
Public Function Env(Value As Variant) As String
    Env = Environ(Value)
End Function
```

I observe this behaviour:

```
$ launchctl setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH "/Users/${USER}/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office"
$ launchctl getenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH  # empty output
$ launchctl setenv DYLDLIBRARYPATH "/Users/${USER}/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office" # Same kind of thing, but no underscores
$ launchctl getenv DYLDLIBRARYPATH # works fine
/Users/alchemyst/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office
```

After running this sequence of commands in my terminal and restarting Excel, I am able to retrieve the contents of "DYLDLIBRARYPATH" using the test spreadsheet. I have also edited the startup.plist and obtained similar results. I appear to be following all the right steps, but it appears that "DYLD_*" is simply not being set when I call setenv. The result is the same if I do it as root.

So basically I am looking for any way in which I can still use this plugin on the Mac.

Versions: MacOS Sierra (10.12.3), Excel 2016 (15.32), CoolProp 6.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> due to SIP, one can no longer set any environment variable which starts with DYLD_

Yes and no. SIP protects **Apple** binaries from `DYLD_`; Microsoft's Excel is not protected by SIP and `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` works as expected.

How do we know this?

There's a library, `libGMalloc.dylib` that can be used to monitor debug allocations of applications. From the terminal, execute the following: -

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib /Applications/Microsoft\ Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Excel
```

You'll see that Excel is launched and works, though a little slower than usual, due to the overhead of the inserted library that's busy monitoring all memory allocations.

In addition, using Activity Monitor and looking at the Excel process's open files, we can clearly see the libGMalloc.dylib that has been inserted into its process.

[image]

I suggest using `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` instead of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and referencing the Coolprop library from the command line, as demonstrated here.

Comment: This is great - it works from the CLI! Is there any way of doing this which will only require once-off intervention? I think it will be very difficult to use this method since you often want to just double-click a spreadsheet icon and have Excel open with the correct libraries already loaded.

Comment: It appears from further testing that specifying the environment on the commandline like this works also for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So there isn't anything special about `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`. We're back to the question of how to do this in general instead of just for one invocation of Excel. At least I now have a partial solution.

Comment: If you double-click an app bundle, macOS will launch whatever is registered, via [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html), with the bundle's URI, specified in the plist; this may not be the app bundle you're clicking on, if you have a copy of the bundle! So, Launch Services gets in the way  and you need to set its environment, perhaps by wrapping calling Excel in another application. It's beyond the scope of the original question. I suggest a new one, on how to set the LS environment.